# Linear regression with a delay : $R(t)= a S(t-\delta) + \epsilon$

Tags: r, time-series, cross-correlation

- $R(t)$ corresponds to soil respiration values in function of the time
- $S(t)$ corresponds to solar radiation values in function of the time

$R(t) = a S(t-\delta) + \epsilon$

How calculate the coeficients $a$ and $\delta$ at each time. I would like at the end a graph with the evolution of $\delta$ and $a$ over the time series.

I would like to do it with the software R.

Thank you for your help

Here is my idea for a :

```
FDC2=subset(FDC_393, SolarRadiation!=0)
n <- 2:length(FDC2$FluxMean)
    Coeff<-c()
    Rsquared<-c()
    for (i in n) {
     F=FDC2[c(1:i),]
     reg2=lm(F$FluxMean ~ F$SolarRadiation)
     Coeff <- append(Coeff,reg2$coefficients[2])
     Rsquared<-append(Rsquared,summary(reg2)$r.squared)
} 

print(Coeff)
print(Rsquared)
t=FDC2$Time_Dec2[-1]
plot(t,Coeff,type="l")
```

Comment: have you looked at the cross-correlation function (`ccf`) ?

Comment: It was my idea for delta but I can't manage to read the script... x=ccf(FDC2$SolarRadiation[i],FDC2$FluxMean[i],lag.max=30,type="correlation",plot=TRUE)
M=max(x$acf) and after my problem is to extract the lag corresponding to this maximum.